# Notification center vs UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, ios5, notifications, uiactionsheet

Maybe somebody faced this kind of trouble: when using UIActionSheet on ios 5 i can call Notification Center. The problem is that i cant touch any event in NC. And it all looks not clean. So, is there some way to disable NC by program or maybe another ways to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean NSNotificationCenter or the visual  element notification center for push notifications? there is a big difference there.

Comment: What do you mean you "can't touch any event in NC"?

Comment: No, this is not NSNotificationCenter, its new feature from ios5. So, when UIActionSheet is visible from app i can slide twice on screen and call NC,  but it appears shadowed. Despite that i can slide under UIActionSheet and make NC disappear, but i cant touch any button on NC(weather and other stuff). Is there some way to disable NC while using my application?? Sorry for not clean explanation at beggining =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out a quick solution:

when the Notification Center shows up, `appDelegate` receives `(applicationWillResignActive:)` and there I post a notification to remove my `UIActionSheet` from the screen. It's not clean but better than it was.